# How can I launch an AppleScript application and run shell scripts from another AppleScript?

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

Here are my files:

launcher.applescript

```
tell application ":path:to:applescript:apps:shell-script-launcher.app" to launch
```

shell-script-launcher.app [AppleScript, saved as Application]

```
 do shell script "say starting script"
```

Desired behavior:

1. Run "launcher.applescript" from AppleScript Editor
2. Listen for "starting script"

Actual behavior:

1. Running the "shell-script-launcher.app" by opening it manually in the finder yields expected behavior
2. Running the "launcher.applescript" opens the "shell-script-launcher.app" but it never executes the shell script.

I've tried saving the app as "Run Only" as well as "Stay Open".  Still no progress.  What do you recommend.  The final result must be an Application instead of an Applescript.

Comment: So changing the launcher.applescript to "activate" instead of "launch" triggered the desired behavior.  But now it runs twice. Can anyone help get me across the line on this one?

Comment: What OSX version are you on?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### *Conceptually*:

- the `run` command launches and runs an application *hidden*
- the `activate` command launches, runs, and *activates* the application (makes it the frontmost application)
- `launch`, [according to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW51), "Launches an application, if it is not already running, but does not send it a run command."

  - for AppleScript-based applications this *should* mean that they're *loaded*, but *not executed* (i.e., their - implicit or explicit - `on run` handler is NOT invoked), but in practice that is not true up to 10.9 - see below.
  - it is unclear (to me) what exactly that means for *non*-AppleScript-based applications

#### Here's how Apple [*thinks* it works with AppleScript-based applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-SW17), which is **only true starting with OSX 10.10 (Yosemite)**:

> A script can send commands to a script application just as it can to other applications. To launch a non-stay-open application and run its script, use a launch command followed by a run command, like this:
>
> `launch application "NonStayOpen"`
> `run application "NonStayOpen"`
>
> The launch command launches the script application without sending it an implicit run command. When the run command is sent to the script application, it processes the command, sends back a reply if necessary, and quits.

#### Broken behavior on OSX 10.8, 10.9 (fixed in OSX 10.10):

**`launch` *by itself* is enough to *run* the application and is indeed the only command that works with AppleScript-based applications**.
Any attempt to execute `run` or `activate` (whether in addition to `launch` or not) runs the application - even *twice* when run from AppleScript editor(!; just once with `osascript`) - but reports failure `<appName> got an error: Connection is invalid`.

This strikes me as **bug**.
Not sure how OSX versions <= 10.7 behave.

Note: I've witnessed the non-executing behavior with `launch` once, but every non-stay-open AppleScript-based test app I've created from scratch on OS X 10.9.2 and OS X 10.8.5 also *executes* the script with `launch` - contradicting what the documentation says.

*Please let me know if your system behaves differently and/or how older versions behave. On what OSX version was the app that doesn't execute with `launch` created?*

On **OSX 10.10**, **behavior is consistent with the documentation**, with one thing worth noting:

- If the intent is to **launch and run in one step, `run application` is sufficient** - no need for a separate `launch application` command first.

#### Options

---

- @user309603's **pragmatic solution** simply uses **`do shell script` with the standard `open` utility** to bypass the problem - this should work, regardless of whether the application is AppleScript-based or not:

```applescript
do shell script "open " & ¬
    quoted form of POSIX path of ¬
    alias ":path:to:applescript:apps:shell-script-launcher.app"
```

---

- If you **know the type of application** you're invoking up front:

  - to run an **AppleScript-based** app: best to use `run script file`, as @regulus6633 recommends - this has the added advantage that the invoked AppleScript-based application can return objects directly to the caller:

```applescript
run script file ":path:to:applescript:apps:shell-script-launcher.app"
```

Note: There's also `load script file`, which indeed lets you merely *load* script code without executing it right away.

- to run **non-AppleScript** apps: use `run` / `activate` to run the app hidden / frontmost:

```applescript
run application ":path:to:applescript:apps:shell-script-launcher.app"
```

---

- You could **use `run`** even with AppleScript-based applications and simply **ignore errors** with `try ... end try`, as @atonus suggests - the downside is that you won't be able to detect actual failure to invoke the application.

You can mitigate this by selectively ignoring only the specific `Connection invalid` error (which assumes this error would not legitimately occur) [no longer needed on OSX 10.10]:

```applescript
try
    run application "Macintosh HD:Applications:_Sandbox-AppleScript0.app"
on error number -609 # 'Connection is invalid' error that is spuriously reported
    # simply ignore
end try
```

---

- Finally, on OSX <= 10.9, you could try to **simply use the `launch` command** (though that didn't work for the OP, possibly due to working on a <= 10.7 OSX version):

```applescript
 launch application ":path:to:applescript:apps:shell-script-launcher.app"
```

However, that is **not advisable** for two reasons:

- In OSX 10.10, Apple has fixed the `launch` behavior to no longer execute also, so your code will break when run there.
- While non-AppleScript apps typically do run (hidden) when invoked with `launch`, the [documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW51) that AppleScript "does not send it a run command" and "allows you to open an application without performing its usual startup procedures, such as opening a new window" - what that exactly means is not clear and different applications seem to handle this differently.

Answer (score 4):

Applescript has the "run script" command. It works on applescripts or applescript applications. So if I have your app on my desktop then this works...

```
set appPath to (path to desktop as text) & "shell-script-launcher.app"
run script file appPath
```

Comment: +1 for telling us about `run script file`, which is the best way to invoke external AppleScript code (though it sounds like the OP may in the end not invoke an AppleScript-based app).

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [open](http://ss64.com/osx/open.html)?

```
do shell script "open 'path/to/applescript/apps/shell-script-launcher.app' && say starting script"
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it between "try" keywords.

```
try
tell application ":path:to:applescript:apps:shell-script-launcher.app" to activate
end try
```

Comment: This works, but by blindly ignoring errors you may miss true errors.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple, you just have to use the normal `do shell script`, for example:

```
do shell script "open " & ¬
    quoted form of POSIX path of ¬
    alias ":path:to:applescript:apps:shell-script-launcher.app"
```

Answer (score 1):

Save your script as an application.
Add the desired script into the Script folder (see path below)

Run as follows, change per type of script you want to run...

```
property theApplicationPath : the path to me as text <br/>
property theShellScriptPath : theApplicationPath & "Contents:Resources:Scripts:test.command"<br/>
property theShellScript : the quoted form of POSIX path of theShellScriptPath<br/>
<br/>
tell application "Terminal" to (do shell script "/bin/bash " & theShellScript)
<br/>
```

Boom, Bob's your uncle!  At least for me.

Comment: this is exactly what I saw looking for thank you! Using this I could load a bash script that I placed inside the application's Scripts folder from within the main.scpt file

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful but I'm not an expert on this subject. I this case I found the double launching behaviour (on Yosemite, I haven't used any other version of OS X) very annoying and digging around I found one can check if it is already running.

This script is so I can launch a new terminal whenever I like.

```
if application "Terminal" is running then
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script ""
    end tell
else
    tell application "Terminal" to activate
end if
```